# Google Play Services Android won't sign in Adobe Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe, google-play-games

Recently I've been trying to get my Adobe Air AS3 Android game to work with Google Play Game Services.
I'm using the **Milkman Native Extension** and Flashdevelop.

I made my own sign in button, and when I press it the standard *"Sign in with your account"* window with all my accounts appears. The first time I sign in with an account it even gives me the standard options to share my game status to my Google+ circles. Then, when I do try to log in, the service shows the standard spinning progress wheel, then disappears, the *"Signed in as PLAYER"* box doesn't show up, and I'm not logged in. The ANE tells me that it's an `unknown_error_code`.

#### Things I've noticed:

- It doesn't let me see a list of achievements or leaderboards either.
- After the first time I log in it just tries
  to log me in again indefinitely.
- The "Apps using google+ data" shows it as a "3rd party app" and not the actual title of the app. EDIT: It now displays it as the correct app for some reason. Still doesn't sign me in though...
- I'm pretty sure this isn't a coding problem.

#### Things I've tried:

- Matching the SHA1 key with the SHA1 key from my p12 key.
- Logging into different accounts.
- Making my accounts tester accounts.
- Using non tester accounts.
- Making new Game Service pages
- Making new application pages
- Changing my app I.D. (`com.blank.mygame`)
- Clearing the "Apps using google+ data"
- Making the Version Number of the game higher than the most recent test account
- Making new Google+ accounts
- Syncing my app to the services page.
- Desyncing my app from the services page.
- Making new OAuth 2.0 client I.D.s.
- Publishing the game services.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Now I can answer my question officially:

I fixed it.
Apparently if you go to the API console and change the Oauth from there the game services doesn't detect it. I originally put in the wrong SHA1 and fixed it through the API and not the google services developer console.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkJS_W-VC9I (it's problem #6 which is really n)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and I solved it by changing the **App/Package ID** at the [Google Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) from:

```
com.developer.appname
```

to:

```
air.com.developer.appname
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simliar issue - the app was asking for permition, but it triggered *onSignInFailed* event.

Tried several things, the problem was with runtime enviroment - everything works correctly when I include it to application. (I was using separate AIR runtime enviroment to decrease the time of publishing the app)